# Jquery not working with the widgets

Tags: jquery

I am using **IGoogle interface** kind of **Jquery and Css** for which im referring some Script tags at the bottom of my aspx page as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/IGUI Utilities/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/IGUI Utilities/jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/IGUI Utilities/inettuts.js"></script>
```

Everything works perfect, but when i drop one more control which needs Jquery interaction again as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs("div.description", { event: 'mouseover' });
    });
</script>
```

**mouseover event doesn't work** :( and *if i drop the same control other than this page it works fine.... I tried changing the order of referring tags but no use*...

Please help me on this...

Comment: I got the solution  ::  **jQuery.noConflict();**   did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with "div.description"? That syntax doesn't look right.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({ event: 'mouseover' });
});
```

Should work.